# SAPUI5: How to create XMLView and its controller in runtime?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I want to create an XMLView in runtime and bind a controller to it. But I don't know how to create and instance of the controller in runtime.

Here is the code that I wrote:

```
var oView = sap.ui.xmlview(sViewId, {
            viewContent: sViewContent,
            controller: ?????
        });
oRouter.getViews().setView(sViewName, oView);
```

Here is the API that I wrote this code based on:

https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.html#.xmlview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two main ways of doing it.
You can either define a new controller class on the fly and then use it to instantiate a new controller instance:

```
var MyController = sap.ui.core.mvc.Controller.extend("MyController", {
    onInit: function() {
        // do something
    }
});
var oView = sap.ui.xmlview(sViewId, {
     viewContent: sViewContent,
     controller: new MyController()
});
```

Or you can use the [sap.ui.controller](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.html#.controller) function to define a new controller and then to obtain an instance of it:

```
// first define the new controller type
sap.ui.controller("MyController", {
    onInit: function() {
        // do something
    }
});
var oView = sap.ui.xmlview(sViewId, {
     viewContent: sViewContent,
     // then instantiate the controller
     controller: sap.ui.controller("MyController")
});
```

If inside the view XML content you reference towards the controller name, then you don't necessarily have to pass the controller instance to the `sap.ui.xmlview` function call. E.g. you can look at the SAPUI5 jsfiddle template: https://jsfiddle.net/nistv4n/93mx0yvt/